# issue with {edit_date}

Tags: zoo-visitor, edit-date

Ok, I have the following:

the edit_date is stored in the exp_channel_titles table in the edit_date field by default.

This is the value 20130320100306 (20/03/2013 10:03:06)

I tested the following tags within a ZooVisitor update form

```
{edit_date}
```

**output:** 08-01-1970

```
{edit_date format="%d-%m-%Y"}
```

**output:** 639874-06-14 00:25

```
{exp:low_nice_date date="{edit_date}" format="%d-%m-%Y"}
```

**output:** 14-06-1974

Running EE v2.5.3 - Build Date: 20120911

kind regards,
Vic

Answer (score 1):

This is because date formatting is not supported inside a Safecracker form. See also http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/zoo-visitor/viewthread/7449#25153

Cheers,
Nico

Comment: I already use an addon: low_nice_date, but the output is 14-06-1974 and it should be 20-03-2013

Answer (score 0):

I too had some issues with datepicker and formatting date in safecracker. This may be of further assistance: [SAEF + Matrix + Date_field + custom layout, datepicker not displaying](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/5901/saef-matrix-date-field-custom-layout-datepicker-not-displaying/5932#5932)